# Comparing Array with multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I have 2 arrays :

```
labels = ["water", "sever", "electricity"];
services = [0:[0:"1",1:"sever"], 1:[0:"3",1:"park"], 3:[0:"4",1:"gas"]];
```

I want to check if **ANY** of `labels` value is in `services` or not (True or False).

What is the best way to archive this using jquery?

**EDIT 1:**

Yes, I made a mistake while asking question, `services` is a JSON Object.

**UPDATE**

Bregi's 2nd solution is what I needed. `.some` is fulfilling purpose.

```
var isInAny = labels.some(function(label) {
  return services.some(function(s) {
    return s[1] == label;
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript syntax

Comment: jQuery does not help here. Check out the Underscore.js library.

Comment: services looks like an object to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`some` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (though you might need to shim it for legacy environments):

```
var isInAny = labels.some(function(label) {
    // since we don't know whether your services object is an actual array
    // (your syntax is invalid) we need to choose iteration/enumeration
    if (typeof services.length == "number") {
        for (var i=0; i<services.length; i++)
            if (services[i][1] == label)
                return true;
    } else {
        for (var p in services)
            if (services[p][1] == label)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

If `services` is really an Array, you could also use

```
var isInAny = labels.some(function(label) {
    return services.some(function(s) {
        return s[1] == label;
    });
});
```

Comment: `services` is an Array and your 2nd solution worked perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those should be braces instead of brackets in `services`

```
labels.some(function (label) {
    for (var x in services) {
        if (services.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            return services[x][1] === label;
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WwsLk/

Comment: `services` is JSON created from database. I am not sure why you said *braces instead of brackets in services*. It will be helpful if you can give some more information about it.  and Yes `.some` is perfectly working as I needed but with some changes in your code (@Bergi's Solution is giving proper results in my case).

Comment: @anand bracket: `[`, brace: `{`.  What changes?

Comment: I am using above code with brackets (`[`) only.

Comment: @anand I understand now.  `services` in your question is not valid JS; just make sure to make it valid for your next question :)

Answer (score 1):

This has often been answered here. You may want to have a look ^^

But, to give you an answer: Use $.each on services to generate a new array with the strings from there and compare this to the labels array.

This should get you an idea:
[Compare two multidimensional arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484126/compare-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: That question has the same title, but a very different topic.

Comment: -1 for commenting without reading complete question.