# How to run the loop inside the loop faster in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two array objects which is of different lengths in which `data.rows` is of length 955 and `place_names` is of length 287. I am running loop inside the loop which takes around 3 minutes to run. Is there any easy and fastest way to run the code below?

```
for (i = 0; i < place_names.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < data.rows.length; j++) {
    if (place_names[i].name === data.rows[j].name) {
      geom.push(data.rows[j].st_asgeojson);
      geom1.push({
        name: data.rows[j].name,
        geometry: data.rows[j].st_asgeojson
      });
      matched_average_value.push(place_names[i].average);
      matched_sum_value.push(place_names[i].sum);
      matched_minimum_value.push(place_names[i].minmum);
      matched_maximum_value.push(place_names[i].maximum);
    }
    else {
      console.log("no matches found");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try this and compare. But I don't think it is gonna make much difference. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xoowvcf9/

Comment: are `i` and `j` local variables ? you could sort both list by name.

Comment: @Hacketo, Sorting will go through another loop right ? But that won't be nested one. Kind of helpful! Also you somewhere need to break a loop I suppose. `if (place_names[i].name === data.rows[j].name)` here ?

Comment: @RayonDabre sorting would allow to stop inner loop when reach the last item that match, and you could start the inner loop at the last item that previously match.

Comment: defining the length of the array before the loop also helps in performace

Comment: remove the `console.log` ... where you have it will result in up to 274000+ pointless console.logs

Comment: @JaromandaX, Let us assume it is just there in development environment...

Comment: You forgot a few `{}`. And as @JaromandaX said, remove the `console.log()` statements!

Comment: @Hacketo: i is global and j is local.

Comment: Well  even console.log is removed, it is bit slower.

Comment: Can we see some data samples? Are names unique?

Comment: Borrowing @RayonDabre code and added a few more tweaks which may or may not help - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5af89yc/2/)

Comment: Never heard of js loops taking _minutes_ to execute.. __Something must be going wrong__ Share some example..

Comment: I suspect your bottleneck is not in the nested loops itselfs but in the work that you do inside them. Maybe you should try a different approach, if your if (place_names[i].name === data.rows[j].name) condition is true in a high percentage of cases.

Comment: @JaromandaX, `break` and _sorting_ together will help I guess...Correct me I am going wrong...

Comment: @Harnish: Start by making `i` a local variable as well. Scope is important for speed. Even a 300k loop should not take minutes. Same for all the other variables you're using…

Comment: Are the names unique per array, do you have a 1-to-1 relationship between the items? Have a look at [my answer to *Compare two multidimensional arrays in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484419/1048572)

Comment: AJaromanda X: the fiddle given by you https://jsfiddle.net/w5af89yc/2/ works little faster than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists `place_names` and `data.rows`. The field you're interested in is the `name` field.

Depending on where you get this data from, it might be better to use a dictionary for this:

```
var dict = {};
place_names.forEach(
    function(place_name) {
        dict[place_name.name]=place_name;
    }
);
```

Now you can loop through your `data.rows`:

```
data.rows.forEach(
    function(row) {
        if(row.name in dict) {
            var place_name = dict[row.name];
            // Do what needs to be done with "row" and "place_name"
        }
    }
);
```

This should reduce your `n^2` algorithm to a `n log n` or even `n` (Depending on JavaScript's dictionary indexing complexity, I'm not sure). This solution assumes that all `place_names[i].name` values are **unique**. If they aren't, then you might want to store a list of all matching `place_names` in your `dict`.